# "sectionIndex" only returns headlines in the first content element

Tags: typo3, typoscript

if i set  "sectionIndex = true", in the menu only the headlines of the first backend element are shown. But i need all headlines of this page.
This is the code of the dropdownmenu:

```
 2 = TMENU
    2 {
        wrap = <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">|</ul>

        noBlur = 1
        expAll = 0
        sectionIndex = true

        NO = 1
        NO.allWrap >
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        CUR = 1
        CUR < .NO
        CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active current">|</li>
        ACT = 1
        ACT < .NO
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>

        IFUSB < .1.IFSUB
        CURIFSUB < .1.CURIFSUB
        ACTIFSUB < .1.ACTIFSUB

        SPC = 1
        SPC.doNotLinkIt = 1
        SPC.doNotShowLink = 1
        SPC.allWrap = <li class="divider"></li>
    }
```

can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any have the same problem:
i have found the answer. You have to add this column:

```
sectionIndex.useColPos = -1
```